# call my web services from other app with javascript?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I got .asmx a web service on my app. I need to call a method from an other app to get statistics from my app. I need it to return XML. the call to the webmethod is done with javascript soap.

**EDIT**
I got the web service working. I can execute code and return a string but it stops there. When I try to pass parameters into the method it wont work and when I try to return a string[] or any other type it wont work either. any ideas? Is there something I need to do passing in parameters?

Comment: It would be easier it you post code fragment of your application which not work, then it wold be easier to help you. Do you use C# or VB? Do you use jQuery in JavaScript part? And so on... Only if I look at your previous question I can suppose that you use C# and jQuery, but a code example would makes a lot of things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do two things.

One: enable [ScriptService] attribute on web method. This allows you to call the webservice 
with javascript. 
[Example](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3820451/Using-ASPNET-ScriptServices-with-Popular-JavaScript-Frameworks.htm)

Two: enable http-post/http-get webservice calls 
[How to enable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267)